# CONTAINS() Formula

Tags: formula, lookup, contains

I have a checkbox formula that evaluates true if:

```
Contains(Text_field__c, Account__r.lookup__r.Name)
```

If i have "test account" in the account__r.lookup__r.Name, and "test account" in the text_field__c it works.
However, if I leave it blank, or type in a random word for text_field__c that does not match account__r.lookup__r.Name and vice versa, it still marks it true.

Shouldn't contains only work if "account__r.lookup__r.Name" is contained in text_field__c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around to this. I just carried over the lookup__r.name into a formula field onto the object with text_field__c. then I used contain there to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [CONTAINS function use cases and examples](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004749&language=en_US&type=1) article.

**Usage**

1. Search for text.
2. Check if an unknown string or character matches a defined set of strings or characters.

> Example of searching for text.

```
CONTAINS(Comments__c,"BadWord")
Returns TRUE if "BadWord" is found anywhere in Comments__c.
```

> Example of searching for  unknown string or characters.

```
CONTAINS("0123456789", TextField__c)
Will return true for TextField__c values such as 1,2,9,01,789, or any other substring of "0123456789"
```

For your question, *If i have "test account" in the account__r.lookup__r.Name, and "test account" in the text_field__c it works. However, if I leave it blank, or type in a random word for text_field__c that does not match account__r.lookup__r.Name and vice versa, it still marks it true.*

The second example is working.

**Update based on comments**

Use `REGEX` instead of `CONTAINS`

```
REGEX(text, regex_text)
```

> The Salesforce regular expression engine matches an entire string as opposed to searching for a match within a string. For example, if you are searching for the name Marc Benioff, use the regular expression, .*Marc Benioff.*, to find a match in a string like the following:

```
According to Marc Benioff, the social enterprise increases customer success.
```

If you use the regular expression, Marc Benioff, the only string that this regular expression will match is:

```
Marc Benioff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Not Null condition on Formula field

```
IF(AND(NOT( ISNULL(Text_field__c)  ), CONTAINS( TRIM(Text_field__c),TRIM(Account__r.lookup__r.Name) , )) ,true,false)
```

Comment: that still does not work, it marks it true if it is blank and contains text still that don't match